# help removing installmac malware

Tags: macos, malware

In a moment of stupidity I installed a program on my OS X 10.8.5 that was suppose to turn my Iphone into a remote for my powerbook.  I was gifted with this hijacker app SearchInstallmac

I've read a lot about it, removed all the files I can find. The list of files I have deleted are found here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5091234?start=30&tstart=0

and  here

http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-genieo/

My Chrome Browser is still trying to re-direct to the malware site.  I have cookies blocked and so it can't redirect but I'd love to remove it completely.

I'm I missing something or a file that still needs to be deleted?  Do I need to reinstall Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I would head straight to sophos where they provide free virus and malware scanning software as well as removal tools.

- http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx

Their product is quite well vetted and used by enterprise and many organizational IT departments. Worst case, you could reboot your Mac into recovery mode and install a fresh OS onto a USB drive and then install the cleaning software there, but from what you've listed a decent tool might clean things up with little muss or fuss.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. The antivirus software my IT department has running on my system didn't catch this nasty bug, but Sophos did.